# Issue with bootstrap button vertical alignement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I have a simple Jade code for my header.jade

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-inverse(role="navigation")
    div.container
        div.navbar-header
            ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left
                li.dropdown
                    a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown')
                        | Menu 
                        b.caret
                    ul.dropdown-menu
                        li
                            a(href='/') A
                        li
                            a(href='/') B                           
                        li.divider
                        li
                            a(href='/') C
                a.navbar-brand(href="/") Brand : Blabla!
        div.navbar-collapse.collapse
            div.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                a.btn.btn-success(href="/login") Se connecter
```

and I have an issue with green button that is not align (verticaly)

here is a screenshot

[image]

So, I just need a stupid alignment between the navbar item (menu, brand, button)
What is strange, it that for text link, this is working and for forms too. But not for button

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/new#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `navbar-btn` class to your `a.btn`. It should center it vertically.

See the [Official Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons) for more information.

Comment: Yes, this is it !  `a.btn.navbar-btn.btn-success(href="/login") Se connecter` Thanks